# jQuery: Having trouble hiding/showing when a div is clicked

Tags: jquery

I am building a homepage with four links that are four different images. When one is clicked, I would like a new image to appear near the corresponding link using jQuerys hide/show effects. Right now I'm having trouble getting it to work.

The HTML:

```
<img src="images/images/grey_shape1.png" class="grey_shape1"/>
<img src="images/images/grey_shape2.png" class="grey_shape2"/>
<img src="images/images/grey_shape3.png" class="grey_shape3"/>
<img src="images/images/grey_shape4.png" class="grey_shape4"/>

<div id="green_box_container">
<a href="#"><div id="green_box1"><img src="images/lilacs_small.jpg" /></div></a>
<a href="#"><div id="green_box2"><img src="images/lilacs_small.jpg" /></div></a>
<a href="#"><div id="green_box3"><img src="images/lilacs_small.jpg" /></div></a>
<a href="#"><div id="green_box4"><img src="images/lilacs_small.jpg" /></div></a>
</div>
```

*Currently I'm using the same image for all 4 links-- will change this later.

When a div is selected, I need two things to happen. One, the selected div gets a bit bigger (this is already working) and two, the new image appears. The latter isn't happening.

The jQuery:

```
// this part is working fine
    $("#green_box_container a").click(function() {
          $(this).children().animate({height:105,width:105}, 'medium')
          $(this).siblings().children().animate({height:80,width:80}, 'medium')
    })

// this isn't
    $("#green_box1").click(function() {
        $(".grey_shape1").show("normal");

        })      
})
```

EDIT: here's a fiddle, too http://jsfiddle.net/vN4hu/

I am just working with #green_box1 at the moment. All help is appreciated!!

Comment: Have you got a [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) to show the issue?

Comment: Is it valid to put `<div>` inside `<a>`?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/vN4hu/  Here you go. This kind of just shows what's working now-- since you can't see my images, you wouldn't be able to tell if a .grey_shape were showing up or not.

Comment: re: Is it valid to put <div> inside <a>?  // It hasn't been a problem so far, but I'm not sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Problem**

The jQuery `show()` method manipulates the element's CSS `display` property. Since your images are hidden with the `visibility` property, i.e. `visibility:hidden;`, the `show()` method has no visible effect over them (pun intended :).

**Solution**

Remove the `visibility` property, and hide your images with the `display` property:

```
img {
   ...
   display:none;
   ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I did some changes and it seems working fine:

### CSS:

```
 .grey_shape1 {
    position: absolute;
    display:none; // <----this
    top: 50px; //<--------this
    left: 50px; //<-------this
    z-index: -3;
 }
```

#### [SEEMS WORKING HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/vN4hu/1/)